# Caret's preProcess command: How is it working?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, normalization, caret

I have a questions about how preProcess in the train function is working.  I am trying to fit a neural network in the caret package using timeSlices.  Here is my code:

```
timeSlices <- createTimeSlices(1:nrow(mytsframe3), initialWindow = 60,
                           horizon = 12, fixedWindow = TRUE)
trainSlices <- timeSlices[[1]]
testSlices <- timeSlices[[2]]

nn <- train(diffREALBRENTSPOT ~ diffF1REALlag + diffF2REALlag, data = mytsframe3[trainSlices[[1]],], method = "mlp"
        , size = 1, preProc = c("center","scale"))
```

I obviously need to scale/center/normalize the data that is fed into the neural network before training.  It says in the caret documentation that, "The function preProcess doesn’t actually pre-process the data. predict.preProcess is used to pre-process this and other data sets", see http://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#centering-and-scaling section 3.6.

My question is, in the code I have written, does the train function scale it somehow or does it need to be scaled/normalized before it's fed into the train function?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be scaled before hand if you are using the `preProcess = c("scale",...)`. Within the train function `predict.preProcess` is run on the data before model training. The advantage of defining it in the train function is you don't have to preprocess the data before running predictions. It is integrated into the model prediction before making predictions from the underlying model; assuming the model is a caret model object of course.

Comment: My second question would then be, when I train the network with option preProc = "range" and then predict the test set using the predict function, I get values from predict that are not normalized.  How would you solve that.  My code is: nn <- train(diffREALBRENTSPOT ~ diffF1REALlag + diffF2REALlag, data = mytsframe3[trainSlices[[1]],], method = "mlp"
            , size = 1, preProc = c("range"))    and for predict: pred <- predict(nn, mytsframe3[testSlices[[1]],])

Comment: @user111417 That is working as intended. The pre-processing only happens to the predictors not the dependent variable. If you want to scale your prediction you will need to do that to the data set before getting to this point. You can view the model details by doing `nn$preProcess`. This might be what you are looking for `train(..., yLimits=c(0,1))`.

Comment: `yLimits` is only a return of the function `train` I tried to add it and it did nothing within the `train` function.

Comment: The reason I ask is because I'd like to normalize the testing set with the same min and max as the training set.